# Active Content Error when using SAP GUI Scripting

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have an issue with active content notification appearing when scripting in SAP GUI. My ActiveX settings for IE are set to allow ActiveX content. Issue only happens when SAP GUI connection is set via script.

Below is the section of code where I am having issue. Opening via a script also causes a different view of SAP GUI to show, which may be part of the issue. Is there a different way to open SAP GUI to avoid the active content notification?

```
'***** Open SAPGUI
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.exec "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\frontend\sapgui\saplgpad.exe"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Application1 = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
Set SAPGUI = GetObject("SAPGUI")

'***** Start Script Engine (disable pop up in SAP settings if applicable or will get error)

Set Application1 = SAPGUI.GetScriptingEngine
  If SAPguiAPP Is Nothing Then
    Set SAPguiAPP = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
  End If
  If Connection Is Nothing Then
    Set Connection = SAPguiAPP.OpenConnection("1C. SAP ECC Production")
  End If

  If Session Is Nothing Then
    Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
  End If
```